# Broke pulse audio and permissions

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I had an issue where pulseaudio would only play sound of a single application at a time.  If you fired up ncmpcpp and then tried to play a game or play youtube, the latter would output no sound. (I never fixed this issue)

Upon some attempts to fix it I installed `alsa-base` which then blew up my audio installation.

I am running:
Ubuntu Server 16.06LTS with i3, but no desktop environment.

Things worked fine from a single audio source, but now I have all sorts of issues I'm not sure how to fix and google searches have failed me.

If I run `pulseaudio`, it'll fail with the following:

```
W: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
```

The output of `aplay -l` is:

```
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

The output of `sudo aplay -l` is:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC1150 Analog [ALC1150 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC1150 Digital [ALC1150 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`pacmd` won't work either, citing no daemon is running.

If I run `pulseaudio -D` then run `pacmd`, it tells me 0 sinks, and 0 cards are available.

I would love to prevent a full OS reinstall and set up so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Alsamixer also does not bring up any available devices.

Answer (score 1):

No, I wasn't trying to run as root as it'd throw an error.

I reinstalled the alsa-base and pulseaudio packages and restarted and it magically worked.  It also fixed the multi-input sound issue so things are fine, but I have no idea what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `export $(dbus-launch)` before starting PulseAudio.

Comment: This got the daemon started but pacmd says there are no sinks, cards, or devices.  what should the permissions be?

Comment: Actually, when you say that you could only play audio on one device at a time... That makes me think that PulseAudio wasn't ever configured correctly and things were just going through ALSA.

Comment: As far as permissions, from what I can tell, it should be handled by systemd-logind. Are any users besides "pulse" in the audio group?

Comment: Adding users to the audio group overrides logind's ability to grant permissions. Also, you're not trying to run PulseAudio as sudo/root, are you?